# Using Greensock Tweenlite to scroll in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gsap

I am trying to use Tweenlite on this because I read that it was simple, but for me it is not. I am trying to pass a function called toScroll from my index.js to my navigation bar and trying to pass the id I want to scroll to when it is called with onClick. If anyone could help me I would be greatly appreciated. The function is getting through to the nav bar, but it throws an error.

This is the error I am getting:

```
bundle.js:160 Uncaught TypeError: _gsap2.default.to is not a function
at App.toScroll (bundle.js:160)
at onClick (bundle.js:20987)
at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:4679)
at executeDispatch (bundle.js:4479)
at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (bundle.js:4502)
at executeDispatchesAndRelease (bundle.js:3932)
at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (bundle.js:3943)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at forEachAccumulated (bundle.js:4779)
at Object.processEventQueue (bundle.js:4148)
```

Index.js:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toScroll = this.toScroll.bind(this);
  }

  toScroll(location) {
    console.log(location)
    TweenLite.to(window, .8, {scrollTo: location});
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <div>
        <Header toScroll={this.toScroll} />
        <Intro id="intro" />
        <WhatIDo id="what" />
        <WhoIAm id="who" />
        <Gallery id="gallery" />
        <Contact id="contact" />
        <Footer />
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

header.js (Navigation bar)

```
const header = (props) => {
  console.log(props.toScroll);
  return (
    <HeaderContainer>
      <HeaderName>
        xxxx xxxxxxx
      </HeaderName>

      <HeaderLinks>
        <List>
          <Item onClick={() => props.toScroll("intro")}>Intro</Item>
          <Item onClick={() => props.toScroll("what")}>What I do</Item>
          <Item onClick={() => props.toScroll("who")}>Who I am</Item>
          <Item onClick={() => props.toScroll("gallery")}>My Work</Item>
          <Item onClick={() => props.toScroll("contact")}>Contact</Item>
        </List>
      </HeaderLinks>
    </HeaderContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, it seems like maybe there is an importing issue going on. From your example code it is unclear how you are importing GSAP, but I will assume you are using ES6 imports. If that's the case, I recall that the minimum version of GSAP that would work with ES6 imports is  1.19.0, so that would be the first thing I would check. From my experience the import should look like

`import TweenLite from 'gsap';`

and

`import scrollTo from '../node_modules/gsap/ScrollToPlugin';`

(note the "node_modules" path, I'm assuming you installed from NPM). I have another project where I use TweenMax and Power4 easing, and I used it like this:

```
import { TweenMax, Power4 } from 'gsap';

export default {
  flash(target, onComplete) {
    return TweenMax.to(target, 0.7, {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,0,.3)',
      repeat: 1,
      repeatDelay: 1.3,
      yoyo: true,
      clearProps: 'backgroundColor',
      onComplete: onComplete,
      ease: Power4.easeInOut
    });
  }
};
```

This project uses GSAP 1.20.3. See if that helps.